# XML to sql with openxml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, openxml

Can anybody help me, why I'm getting nothing out of the XML-Document? I think it has to do with the first line, because if I erase this and all other lines with something like "xsi:" or "ns3:" I get the expected output "Biking".

Code:

```
DECLARE @XmlDocumentHandle int
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(max)
SET @XmlDocument = 
'<TrainingCenterDatabase xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityGoals/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/UserProfile/v2" xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ProfileExtension/v1">
  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Biking">
      <Id>2014-09-28T08:48:39.000Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2014-09-28T08:48:39.000Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>17766.56</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>65047.04</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>15.639999</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>4113</Calories>
        <AverageHeartRateBpm>
          <Value>142</Value>
        </AverageHeartRateBpm>
        <MaximumHeartRateBpm>
          <Value>182</Value>
        </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
        <Track>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2014-09-28T08:48:40.000Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>48.18774196319282</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>16.302834944799542</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>83.5999984741211</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>3.180000066757202</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm>
              <Value>94</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Extensions>
              <ns3:TPX>
                <ns3:Speed>0.0</ns3:Speed>
              </ns3:TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2014-09-28T08:48:45.000Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>48.18779996596277</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>16.30263394676149</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>83.4000015258789</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>19.360000610351562</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm>
              <Value>100</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Extensions>
              <ns3:TPX>
                <ns3:Speed>0.0</ns3:Speed>
              </ns3:TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
        </Track>
     </Lap>
      <Creator xsi:type="Device_t">
        <Name>Garmin Edge 705</Name>
        <UnitId>3417593319</UnitId>
        <ProductID>625</ProductID>
        <Version>
          <VersionMajor>3</VersionMajor>
          <VersionMinor>3</VersionMinor>
          <BuildMajor>0</BuildMajor>
          <BuildMinor>0</BuildMinor>
        </Version>
      </Creator>
    </Activity>
  </Activities>
  <Author xsi:type="Application_t">
    <Name>Garmin Connect API</Name>
    <Build>
      <Version>
        <VersionMajor>16</VersionMajor>
        <VersionMinor>15</VersionMinor>
        <BuildMajor>4</BuildMajor>
        <BuildMinor>4</BuildMinor>
      </Version>
    </Build>
    <LangID>en</LangID>
    <PartNumber>003-F3589-01</PartNumber>
  </Author>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlDocumentHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

SELECT    *
FROM      OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, 'TrainingCenterDatabase/Activities/Activity')
           WITH (
                    Sport nvarchar(max) '@Sport'
                )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XmlDocumentHandle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT    *
FROM      OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, '*[local-name()=''TrainingCenterDatabase'']/*[local-name()=''Activities'']/*[local-name()=''Activity'']')
           WITH (
                    Sport nvarchar(max) '@Sport'
                )
```

You may [learn about XML namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx).

In that particular case the expression xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" in TrainingCenterDatabase node defines default namespace, so all descendant elements bounds to this namespace unless specified otherwise.

Your XPath is attempting to address elements that are bound to the default "no namespace" namespace, so they don't match.

You can execute

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, '.')
```

to see namespace of every element in 'namespaceuri' column of result table.